# Email confirmation and page not found

Tags: support

I have tried today to register for my friend from my laptop using another browser. I have found two issues:

First: we opened his email from my already logged in browser and clicked on the confirmation link.
a message:

> You have successfully completed signup.

but his account never activated.

Second: in the **Tour** we have tried to click [full list of sites.](https://stackexchange.com/sites)
but it redirected us to an error page.

Regards,

Comment: `http://stackexchange.com/sites` returns an error for me too.

Comment: Or it did do. Now working.

Comment: for me still error page

Comment: Maybe it depends what server you hit then?

Comment: Works for me, but if you hit a rogue server you might stay in trouble...

Comment: I have taken a rogue server out of rotation, so you should be able to access the page no problem now.

Comment: yes, it works now :)

Comment: @Oded re-occuring problems?

Comment: @rene - looks like. It is a specific server that seems to be the problem, though we haven't been able to find a smoking gun - can't figure out the underlying issue yet.

Comment: @Oded If you **do** find a smoking gun in the server-room then that might be the issue.

Comment: what about account activation is it a bug or normal? 
should I add it in separate post?