# Stack Overflow buttons not working

Tags: support, bug

**Not Working:**

- The recent achievements: reputation, badges, and privileges earned
- Recent inbox messages
- Help button
- Commenting and Deleting on Question/Answer, Giving vote to comment, Vote Question and Answer, Posting Answer to a question **(Exactly similar as Suspended account)**

**Winter Bash** Icon is not appearing beside the achievement icon.

There are many more problems I am facing with my account. Please help me.

Here is what is I am facing right now. These were working ***30 minutes ago***, but not now.

[image]

Here is my chrome allowing JS in every site

[image]

Here is what my Console showing

[image]

Here is what my Network tab shows

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is what I'm getting on clicking recent achievements and recent inbox messages,

In **Chrome**,

[image]

In **Firefox**,

[image]

In **Internet Explorer**

[image]

Comment: Your JavaScript is disabled for some reason, or the CDN is blocked on your side.

Comment: Open up the developer console to find out what is wrong.

Comment: I know people here like to do negative voting, rather actually helping others. I'm really sick of it.

Comment: bleh, so you got virtual -1 that doesn't even affect your rep. END OF THE WORLD.

Comment: Anyway if you still didn't rage quit, have a look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/152859) under "What else do I need?".

Comment: Negative voting on SO Meta most of the time means that the user disagrees with your post. It does not affect your reputation, and it does not say anything about the question itself (however that might be possible, ofcourse).

Comment: @ShadowWizard check my question thoroughly

Comment: And try removing your cache.

Comment: Still facing same after clearing the cache @KevinVoorn

Comment: I did. It's caused by CDN being blocked on your side, see the "Network" tab of Chrome.

Comment: Is it also happening in other browsers you try?

Comment: Yes same is happening in firefox and ie

Comment: What is `tracert cdn-prom.sstatic.net` returning?

Comment: Add the output of the network tab of the dev console in Chrome after you cleared the cache

Comment: [Here](http://prntscr.com/5mmof3) is what the command is returning @rene

Comment: And the [output](http://prntscr.com/5mmouw) of the network tab.

Comment: It did finish without errors?

Comment: Nope @rene here is the completed [report](http://prntscr.com/5mmpcn)

Comment: You need to mark disbale cache and then reload the page while keeping the networktab open....

Comment: http://prntscr.com/5mmrbr http://prntscr.com/5mmrg6 http://prntscr.com/5mmrkw http://prntscr.com/5mmrop

Comment: Lets see I will do it, @Sompuperoo but I don't think it will work

Comment: I'm not sure if I have seen everything but you might just hit a [rogue webserver](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277628/email-confirmation-and-page-not-found#comment120766_277628). That needs a dev or sysop to confirm though.

Comment: Well @Sompuperoo that doesn't works also, tried everything you said, any other solution, cause thing is same

Comment: @rene is there is anymore solution, cause it's really hurting me bad.

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. You could try the mobile site, or use a different ISP (use your phone operator for example) or use TOR to rule out that your ISP is blocking/fiddling with content but as long as no more reports come in it looks like a localized issue only affecting you.

Comment: I feeling same @rene but there is no other way to check it out for me cause I don't have phones that having this facility. Thanks for all the help you guys did tried, but I will look for a solution as early as possible from administration.

Comment: Tried browser in "Private Mode"?

Comment: No @GuilhermeNascimento that is also not worked, [here](http://prntscr.com/5mn3hp) is what I get when I clicked those buttons

Comment: You are using proxy in "Windows config" (*non browser*) or in "router"?

Comment: No I'm not using any proxy neither in windows config or in router.

Comment: Is it the same via https?

Comment: Yes @sth i tried everything, and check what I said it was working fine since all the day just got these problems suddenly, also never occurs to me before.

Comment: That `http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=a95ae9720f1d` file looks like it is corrupted or truncated. The file sizes I see are 12KB/32.1KB not 5.5KB/12.8KB.

Comment: But I think that is server problem my laptop is okay, cause every other site including other stack overflow sites are working fine even meta too doing good. Problem lies in stackoverflow main site only I don't know.

Comment: @Skynet Have you tried an `ipconfig /flushdns`?

Comment: @MartinSmith Are compressed files, no? I think it is not corrupted.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento the javascript console says "unexpected end of input" for the same file in the screenshot in the question.

Comment: @Skynet I did not see your answer because you did not use the `@...`

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks, I had not noticed.

Comment: Yes @cybermonkey tried but as per all others this is too having no effects on the problem solving.

Comment: Possibly related?: I get timeouts ("you can only X every X seconds) without doing anything even _once_. Nothing suspicious network-wise, except the error response. This happens intermittently everywhere (closing, showing up/downvotes, flagging)

Comment: @keyser I'm still under same situation and yet other sites are working fine like meta, Ask Ubuntu, Unix & Linux, etc.